# Что за оператор такой "" (двойные кавычки)?

Tags: c++

В общем вопрос в заголовке, что за перегружаемый(если уместно применить к этому слово перегружаемый) оператор "" и зачем он используется?

```
long double operator "" _w(long double);
std::stringoperator "" _w (const char16_t* , std::size_t) ;
unsigned operator "" _w(const char*);
int main {
1.2_w; // вызов operator " " _w (1.2L)
u"one"_w; // вызов operator "" _w (u"one", 3)
12_w; // вызов operator " " _w ("12")
"two"_w; // ошибка: нет применимой литеральной операции
}
```

Comment: Кавычки? Пробел? Покажите код с тем оператором

Comment: Код покажите, где он используется

Comment: @AntonShchyrov кода где это используют я не видел, это из стандарта. И я честно говоря вообще не понимаю зачем это нужно. Называется это литералы определяемые пользователем.User-defined literals

Comment: @gil9red отредактировал

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Приведу пример, для чего это может быть использовано:

```
constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _kb ( unsigned long long _bytes)
{
    return _bytes * 1024;
}

constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _mb ( unsigned long long _bytes)
{
    return _bytes * 1024_kb;
}
```

Данные операторы позволяют затем в коде использовать конструкции вида:

```
int64_t buffer = 50_mb;
```

Что по факту будет преобразовано в

```
int64_t buffer = 52428800;
```

Но, на мой взгляд, запись `50_mb` сама за себя говорит что это за число.

Так же такой механизм удобно использовать для обозначения времени:

```
 constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _sec ( unsigned long long _sec)
 {
     return _sec * 1000;
 }

 constexpr unsigned long long operator"" _min ( unsigned long long _min)
 {
     return _min * 60_sec;
 }
```

И далее использовать как:

```
int delay = 15_min;
```

Answer (score 3):

### Это пользовательские литералы.

Подробнее можно почитать по запросу в гугле, или, например, [на хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/140357/) .

Также стоит почитать [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) .

Comment: Благодарю, странно но сам я этой статьи не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>



int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    //3s - пользовательский литерал, определённый в std::chrono_literals
    std::chrono::milliseconds interval = 3s;

    /// выведет 3000 - 3000 миллисекунд
    std::cout << interval.count() << std::endl;
    ///А ещё есть префиксный строковый литерал, вопринимающий символы как есть
    ///Выведет \n\n
    std::cout << R"(\n\n)" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Пользовательские литералы, которые Вы сами определяете, необходимо отделять символом подчёркивания, чтобы они не конфликтовали с литералами, входящими в стандартную библиотеку - как `3s` из `std::chrono_literals` в примере